# Schedule bootstrap popup in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, notifications, popup

I work with an ASP.NET MVC application. One of the functions of it is to notify users about specific event based on current date (say, tomorrow is the deadline for verification of a single piece of equipment). Data about the deadline is inside a table in the database (DB-first approach).

But I do not have a single idea about how it is to be performed. I suppose Bootstrap functionality can be employed and I'm sure this functionality is well-known (like birthday notifications in social networks etc.), but I have no single clue about how it can be managed. Any assistance is highly appreciated :)

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:** As I see, some clarification needs to be provided. I do understand the basic idea behind the scene, but I lack the knowledge of the instruments and best practices. First, I wonder where the check method is to be implemented so that the data can be viewed in the popup window (base controller? Something else?); second, I wonder what is the best way popup or notification window can be implemented (partial view, section, notify.js window etc.) and how it can be performed; third, isn't it better to implement it via SignalR push notifications and how it can be performed. Sorry for previous inconvenience.

Comment: you need to call a check method on startup that (any notifications for todaysDate + 1) and display it on the view as you want, on application start

Comment: @YashSoni On application start? Are you suggesting the OP should restart an ASP.NET MVC application daily for running that check? That's the most ridiculous I've read here

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i meant ,whenever the user opens the website, or calls that specific controller for e.g Home Controller , there should be a check method called

Comment: That's *very* far from "on application start", **very** far

Comment: to be specific, whenever you open a mvc site, application_Start method is being called from global.asax file, i don't know how well versed you are but , m sorry :-)

Comment: I also suppose some other variant is more suitable for popup window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JavaScript function which runs recursively in a given interval.
In this JS function make an AJAX call to the backend retrieve the relevant data.

```
function load() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/EventController/Event",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (eventData) {
            // load the popup 
            // with necessary data

            setTimeout(load, 1000*60*10); // calls the same method in another 10 mins
        },
        error: function (jqXHR) {
            setTimeout(load, 1000*60*10);
        }
    });
}
```

Call the load() method in $(document ).ready() function.

Or you can ideally use an **HTML 5 web worker** which runs in the background and perform the above AJAX call and show the popup.

Once the required data is retrieved you can simply embed it into a modal popup or a dialog.

For the pop up It would be easily achievable by referring one of the below suggestions.

https://www.pair.com/support/kb/how-to-use-jquery-to-generate-modal-pop-up-when-clicked/

Good Luck..!